# Using JDBC when server name contains a backslash (localhost\TESTDATA)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

thanks for taking the time to read this.  I'm completely stumped by what is probably a simple thing.  I am trying to make a connection to my SQL database, the following tends to work:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.100.200;DatabaseName=master;user=sa;password=";
```

However when my name contains a backslash, for example "localhost\TESTDATA I cannot seem to get it working, I am getting

"java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name 'localhost\TESTDATA'."

when I use the following:

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost\\TESTDATA;DatabaseName=master;user=sa;password=";
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried normal slashes? Like "localhost/TESTDATA" ?

Comment: This is wrong.  The host is about the server.  It should be an IP address or alias.  There's no forward slash.  You misunderstand.

Comment: What does TESTDATA represent? Why do you need it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The jtds driver does not have the same syntax as the ms driver. You should send the instance name as a property, i.e. like this:

```
"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/master;instance=TESTDATA;..."
```

Also notice that the database name is sent as `/master` instead of as a property. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the port number, just giving the server name won't work. So it should be like

```
String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:<portnumber>/TESTDATA;DatabaseName=master;user=sa;password="
```

;

Comment: This only matters if the SQL server  is running on a non-default port.  the driver will use 1433 if you don't specify.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as a backslash in a host name.  You need to do `ping hostname` from a command prompt, and whatever you use for hostname goes in the URL for JDBC.

You can also use the IP address, but if you can ping by the hostname it will work.

See here: http://www.wikihow.com/Ping-an-IP-Address

Figure out the right host name first.