# Tomcat connection pool cannot connect to server with \ in his name

Tags: java-8, connection-string, tomcat8

I'm trying to connect to a database using the Tomcat connectionpool. On our staging db it is working just fine. But on our production sql we have a server name with a / in it. So in the connectionString in my context.xml file I tried to place the \ in the name but did no work.

The connection string looks like:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/database" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxTotal="50" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="10000"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://serverXX\XXXX:1433;databaseName=dbNameXXX;"
        username="userX" password="PasswordXX" />
```

Can someone help me with this?

It looks like that the datasource from this resource contains 2x the \ in the url. But this is not correct and should only have one \ in the url.

Comment: The backslash is a special character in most situations. Did you try putting two backslashes into your configuration?

Comment: yes I tried that already. But when placing two \ in the connection url it shows 4 \in the datasource url when debugging the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766908/using-jdbc-when-server-name-contains-a-backslash-localhost-testdata

Comment: @JimmyD can you scape that 4 times? It might sound funny, but 2 slashes are needed for java itself (to escape a String in general) and two more might be required by something else...